# Circle Point Region Puzzle

Tags: mathematics, pattern

Below puzzle was given to me by my friend. His college professor gave him to solve.

Answer is one (real) word only.

**HINT**: Turn around when one could be confused

Here is the puzzle:

[image: Region Points]

Comment: the instructions are missing two very important points - that you are asked for the **maximum** number of regions, and that you draw lines from each point to each other point - for example in the "4 points" you draw the diagonals of the quadrilateral, not just the sides. As given, this is "please recognize this well known math problem" rather than a complete puzzle.

Comment: Per [your next question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/125758/find-the-riddle-word?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment349527_125758), I'm suspicious that this is actually from some sort of competition.

Answer (score 2):

> Turn around when one could be confused

This is called a

> [double-take](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/double-take). [As is well known](//youtu.be/NOCsdhzo6Jg), the first five numbers in the sequence above are 1, 2, 4, 8, and 16, doubling each time, but it's not actually a doubling sequence — because the sixth term is 31. This **take**-away (subtraction) from the **double** causes you to do a **double-take**.

Comment: Appreciate the effort. think double-take are two words.  But any other guesse?